# Google Play - wrong minimum API detected

Tags: android, google-play

I've just uploaded my apk to the Google Play console. The problem is that on the app site on Google Play **REQUIRES ANDROID** field is wrong. It shows `1.6` while I've set it in the Manifest file to `2.3`. So I suppose now users with lower APIs can download my app and get bad experience as it will crash. Whats wrong?

fragment of the Manifest.xml:

```
 <uses-sdk
 android:minSdkVersion="9"
 android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a Google Play issue and it has gone itself after few hours being published. I'm just wondering if users with android lower than 2.3 could download my app then.

Comment: What a "genius" downvoting this... and why?

Answer (score 46):

This issue still persists (as of December 2013), but only in Beta and Alpha tracks.
The correct **"Requires Android"** version will be displayed as soon as you promote your application to Production.

Comment: Anyone knows if this bug affects <compatible-screens> too? In the manifest I set this just for small and normal, but Google Play allows me to install the alpha version in a 10" tablet.

Comment: Still persists as of June 2014... arg!

Comment: Thanks! I was worried about that, but now I can publish my app publicly knowing this :)

Comment: Pfffff Still persists as of november 2014

Comment: @TiagoA. in my case compatible-screens work correctly in Beta track.

Comment: Still going strong, December 2014

Comment: Still persists of February 2015! Damn you Google!

Comment: Still persists of June 2015! Thanks Google for stealing half a day of work!

Comment: Still persists of December 2016!

Comment: Still persists as of October 2017