# Different Minimum API level in Android Manifest and in Google Developer Publish console

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest

Why is that on my application, the minimum Android API level should be 11 but google play (google published console) says that my minimum is 7?

[image]

My Android Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.toksis.pvscreen"
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName=".1001" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
        .......I had removed the other parts of the manifest.....
```

Comment: Also you version name and version code seem to be different .. Are you seeing the correct apk? Or may be you are updating your apk but seeing the details for your old apk..

Comment: I had changed it.. sorry Wrong picture. Where do google play check what minimum apk you are using? I think it is not on android manifest. Based on this error.

Comment: This problem happen only in Beta and Alpha 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16667093/google-play-wrong-minimum-api-detected

Comment: I already published it.... It still happened.