# Google Play shows wrong minSdkVersion for Android app

Tags: android, air, android-manifest

I added `android:minSdkVersion="14` to the manifest of my Android app to only allow Android 4+ devices but Google Play shows that my app *Requires Android 1.6 and up*. Is there anything wrong with my manifest?

```
<android>
   <manifestAdditions>
      <![CDATA[
        <manifest android:installLocation="auto">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="21" />   
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
</manifest>]]>
    </manifestAdditions>
  </android>
```

I used the Adobe AIR SDK 17 and packaged the app through ADT (command line).

Comment: If you are using android studio, your manifest version will always be overridden in build.gradle.

Comment: @Krupal I'm using Adobe AIR with ADT command line

Comment: Check your build.gradle file ... if possible share

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug on Google Play! (it affects Beta and Alpha apps - I guess your app is in that state?) Check your APK details in the Developer Console for the API level - as long as it's correct your set. It should show the correct API level as soon as you publish the app to production.

Comment: If your app is not yet in production, then I agree with @Robert. This happened to me and as soon as I moved the app to production, it showed the correct information in the Play Store entry :-)

Comment: @Robert Instead of paraphrasing you could simply link my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/20771558/1233652

Comment: Hey, does this issue still persists? I am using ionic and have defined `minSdkVersion` as 16 in `config.xml` but the Play Console picks up 19 (This is for Beta releases). 
Is it this or am I missing something?